# Code block shows differently in preview from post

Tags: bug, status-completed, code-formatting

Using a code block after

1. a list
2. a seperator

   ---

   This code block does not appear as code in the final post, 
   but it does in the preview below the editor.

Comment: You need to put an empty line before the code, and sometimes a `<!— break -->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. This is one of those case where there's really not one single "correct" way, because Markdown has quite a few syntax ambiguities, and the client-side and server-side versions took different approaches.

The preview now matches your final version.